# Using HTML, PHP and Ajax in the same file

Tags: php, html, ajax

Good morning everyone as an attempt to re-learn web programming I am trying to make a simple mailing Form in a self contained html file, so no include, no outside reference using HTML php and Ajax. The point is to make a stand alone html that won't refresh when submitting the form.

I have the html form as follow:

```
<form class="form2" action="" method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<div class="formtitle">Inscrivez-vous à notre infolettre</div>
<div class="input">
<div class="inputtext">Nom: </div>
<div class="inputcontent">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="input">
<div class="inputtext">Courriel: </div>
<div class="inputcontent">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons"> <span id="error" style="display:none; color:#F00">Some Error!Please Fill form Properly </span> <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">All the records are submitted!</span>
<input class="greybutton" type="submit" value="Inscrivez-moi" />
</div>
</form>
```

Then I have my Ajax listen for the submit button clic:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {

$.ajax({
data:$(this).serialize(),
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
console.log(data);
$("#success").show().fadeOut(5000); //=== Show Success Message==
},
error:function(data){
$("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
}
});
e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
});
});
</script>
```

and finally I have the typical mail php code:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = "Veuillez m'ajouter à votre newsletter";
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myMail@MyDomain.com";
$subject = "Newsletter";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to ever reach the php as no mail are sent or success/error message. I doubled and tripled checked all the arguments that are passed and everything seem in order.

Thank you for your time and for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Your .ajax() call is missing a critical URL parameter.

Comment: was about to say the same thing as j08691

Comment: Are you actually running a valid mail server on your server? With appropriate domains, etc? Your emails are going to take a long walk off a short pier if not.

Comment: Your ajax call isn't referencing your PHP form processor. It should contain a url to post against. In addition, your PHP probably should return a JSON response. In the current form, I think it will always hit the success callback even when PHP has an error.

Comment: @Jared Yes I am running everything on a valid web/mail server.

Comment: Good deal. I see a fair number of questions in here where people wonder why the can't get it to work like in the online tutorial they read with no understanding of how email works.

Comment: There should be a place in hell for putting everything in one file...

Comment: @j08691 From what I read the URL: parameter is not needed for inpage code but then again there is a lot of false things on the interwebs! So adding URL: and leaving it empty should do the trick?

Comment: @baldrs it's for learning purpose, I'm a seasoned C++ programmer and I know exactly what you mean by that

Comment: In theory you should be able to leave the URL empty as it will default to the page it's on. I never linked that, and always specify the URL. Try it and see what you get. Also be sure to debug with the browser's tools to see what's being sent back and forth, and for any errors.

Comment: Regarding your question, no mail could mean that it is not set up on your machine. You could review your `php.ini` to see if there any config, and configure it accordingly. Or just try to run the code on the server, if you have access to any.

Comment: `mail` returns truthy value, but it relies on a `sendmail` or other config to work, so if it is not configured, emails are just sent to the void.

Comment: @baldrs I know the set up of the server is correct as I often use it in C# and did some test with copy/paste code from a friend, but good thinking

Comment: @j08691 so if you leave the URL empty it does default to the page it's on using `URL: '',` So the missing URL param is necessary after all, don't beleive all you read on the interwebs!

Comment: Thank you all for your time helping an old school programmer understand the basics of web programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your PHP code in an other page as called : api_newsletter.php

Change your Php code by :

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = "Veuillez m'ajouter à votre newsletter";
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myMail@MyDomain.com";
    $subject = "Newsletter";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true)); 
    }else {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false)); 
    }
?>
```

Then in your ajax code simply do :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        url : '/api_newsletter.php',
        success:function(data){

            console.log(data);
            var rsp = $.parseJSON (data)

            if(rsp["success"] == true){

                $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000); //=== Show Success Message==

            }else {

                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====

            } 
        },
        error:function(data){

                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====

        }
    });

    e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===

  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried it both in different files and in the same file using the `URL:'',` and they both work wonderfully! Thank you for your time and helping me understand where I was wrong!